# Parent | Child DataFrame to balanced Hierarchy

Tags: python, dataframe, recursion

I'm attempting to take a Data Frame with two columns, a Parent and Child and effectively 'flatten' it.

Input

```
Parent | Child
A         B
A         C
C         D
D         E
B         T
```

Output

```
level0 | level1 | level2 | level3
A         B         T
A         C         D        E
```

the only methods i've been able to figure out thus far is converting the DataFrame to a list of tuples and running something like this:

```
test = []
parents = set()
children = {}
for c,p in ancestry2:
    #print(c,p)
    parents.add(p)
    children[c] = p

# recursively determine parents until child has no parent
def ancestors(p):
    return (ancestors(children[p]) if p in children else []) + [p]

# for each child that has no children print the geneology
for k in (set(children.keys()) - parents):
    #print(k)
    test.append(ancestors(k))
    print('/'.join(ancestors(k)))
```

but this results in "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" and if i increase the recursion limit obviously Python crashes.  I'm dealing with <100k records in total.

Any thoughts?  Is there a better way to 'flatten' a parent child relationship?

I suppose it would be easier to move this over to SQL and use a CTE to achieve the desired effect.. but i'd like to learn how to do this in Python.